# Variable is not changing when adding in swift

Tags: swift

Currently, I am trying to make it so when a cell in a table view is clicked on it adds to a variable. Although, when I print the variable when running the app it just prints 10 over again no matter how many times I click a cell.

**Here is my code for the second tableView**{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        //Used to track the number of times the the second tableView was tapped

        if (tableView == secondTable){
            //Function to disable the timer from being used if timer is running
            if isTimerRunning == true {

            }else{

                var tableView2Taps = 0

            //Transfer data to variable to the timer
             selectedindex = indexPath.row

            if (selectedindex == 0){
                seconds = 3600
                secondsreset = 3600
                tableView2Taps += 10

            }
                if (selectedindex == 1){
                seconds = 2700
                secondsreset = 2700
                tableView2Taps += 10
            }
                if (selectedindex == 2){
                seconds = 1800
                secondsreset = 1800
                tableView2Taps += 10
            }
                if (selectedindex == 3){
                seconds = 1200
                secondsreset = 1200
                tableView2Taps += 10
            }
                if (selectedindex == 4){
                seconds = 600
                secondsreset = 600
                tableView2Taps += 10

            }
                print(tableView2Taps)


            }

            //Prevents the user from changing settings when the timer is running
            if isTimerRunning == false{

        if  tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{

            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

        }else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark}
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem of scopes.. You are declaring `tableView2Taps` every time the user selects a row.

You need to declare the `tableView2Taps` variable outside the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

Like this:

```
var tableView2Taps = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
...
}
```

Doing this, `tableView2Taps` becomes an instance variable and the value will be preserved even after the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` ends.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are setting it back to 0 every time a selection occurs. Your problem is with this line here:

```
var tableView2Taps = 0
```

Try storing the above as a variable on the view controller instead.